# Parsing CSV to get specific columns

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I have a CSV file with several headers.

I only need about 5 of these columns.

I'm trying to get these into a more manageable format (variables?) so I can then do a check on their values.

I have the following code:

```
    $headers    = array('NAME', 'EMAIL');
    $picked     = array();
    $theData    = array();
    $isFirstRow = true;
    if (($handle = fopen($uploadedFile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $numCols = count($data);
            $row     = array();

            if($isFirstRow) {
                for($c=0; $c<$numCols; $c++) {
                    if(!in_array($data[$c], $headers)) {
                       continue;
                    } else {
                        $picked[] = $c;
                        $isFirstRow = false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for($c=0; $c < $numCols; $c++) {
                    if(in_array($c, $picked)) {
                        $row[] = $data[$c];
                        $theData[] = $row;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        fclose($handle);


    }
    var_dump($theData);
```

This outputs the following:

```
array (size=xxxxxx)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'John Doe' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'John Doe' (length=8)
      1 => string 'johndoe@test.com' (length=16)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'Jane Doe' (length=8)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Jane Doe' (length=8)
      1 => string 'janedoe@test.com' (length=16)
```

Obviously this isn't the expected output

I'd like something more like:

```
array (size=xxxx)
  0 =>
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'John Doe' (length=8)
      1 => string 'johndoe@test.com' (length=16)
  1 =>
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Jane Doe' (length=8)
      1 => string 'janedoe@test.com' (length=16)
```

I'not sure why its adding the extra arrays.

Anyone have an idea?

Thanks

EDIT

My CSV looks like this;

```
NAME,EMAIL
John Doe,johndoe@test.com
Jane Doe,janedoe@test.com
```

Comment: Your if/else block has no braces but two lines of code.

Comment: What does your csv look like?

Comment: @veelen I've added the CSV info

Comment: @kinghfb I've added in the braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: New answer.

So there's a somewhat convoluted solution that does this:

- Takes your CSV data
- Combine the numeric key data with ALL available headers, giving you a key => value array
- Intersect this with your ALLOWED headers
- Add this to the final data array
- Removes the header row

There we go. It's awful to read, but it seems to be fine. As all the array manipulation is C based, it should be faster than manipulating thousands of rows in PHP.

```
    $availableHeaders = array('NAME', 'THING', 'EMAIL');
    $headers    = array('NAME', 'EMAIL');
    $theData    = array();

    if (($handle = fopen($uploadedFile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $theData[] = array_intersect_key(array_combine(array_values($availableHeaders), array_values($data)), array_flip($headers));
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

    array_shift($theData); // Remove headers
```

Comment: Would this replace the current `$theData[]` array?

Comment: This will add only those two columns per entry. However, I'm just double-checking if fgetcsv assigns keys or numeric indexes. I have a sneaking suspicion it just users numeric indexes...

Comment: The current problem is, that the more columns I add, the more arrays are added. 1 column = 1 array, 2 columns 2 arrays (as my question) 3 columns 3 arrays etc etc

Comment: When I add that, I just get the column names in the array, not the values of the rows...

Comment: Yep. I've updated my answer with a solution. It returns an array with key => value pairs

Answer (score -1):

Example .csv:

```
IGNORE1,NAME,EMAIL,IGNORE2,IGNORE3
-1,John Doe,johndoe@test.com,-1,-1
-1,Jane Doe,janedoe@test.com,-1,-1
```

Code:

```
$headers    = array('3' => 'NAME', '4' => 'EMAIL');
$theData    = array();
$isFirstRow = true;
$rowsToKeep = array();
if (($handle = fopen($uploadedFile, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if ( $isFirstRow ) {
            $rowsToKeep = array_intersect($data, $headers);
            $theData[] = $rowsToKeep;
            $isFirstRow = false;
        } else {    
            $theData[] = array_intersect_key($data, $rowsToKeep);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => NAME
            [2] => EMAIL
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => John Doe
            [2] => johndoe@test.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => Jane Doe
            [2] => janedoe@test.com
        )

)
```

Comment: What happens if the columns are in a different order? It's why I was basing on column name, rather than what key it was in the header.

Comment: My response includes everything you need to test the code.  It doesn't care what order your columns are in.  It uses the names you specify in $headers to identify the columns that should be stored in $theData.  I strongly recommend getting to know the functions at http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php.